# Want to expand the search input to the left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to expand the search box to the left but somehow it takes the width and expands to the right. I tried to give the margin-left but still it doesn't work.

Here it is expanding to right but i want it to expand to left. I tried adding padding left but it is getting affected inside the box and not outside it.

```css
.search-click {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  background-size: 22px;
  background-position: 13px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 363px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 21px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  margin-top: 54px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  //margin-left: -410px;
}

.search-click:focus {
  width: 800px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.search-click input {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-click" placeholder="Search ports, countries, international code port" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by expanding to the left? Do you want it to be right aligned?

Comment: when i click on it it is getting expanded to the right. but it should rather expand towards left @JadenJin

Comment: `.search-click input ` does not exist.

Comment: if i remove it then too nothing specific happens it is just for the background @Gerard

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet" I just get a blank area.  Did you forget the HTML that this CSS is supposed to work with?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's because `margin-left` is set to `-410px`, remove that then you can see the input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For width transition in left, I have changed input's position to right. Changed `position: absolute` and `right: 0; top: 0`.

```css
.search-click {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  background-size: 22px;
  background-position: 13px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 21px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}

.search-click:focus {
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-click" placeholder="Search ports, countries, international code port" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want expand it from the right, just add `text-align: end;` in the `.search-click`.